# How to create Oracle object type with collection as attrubuteobject type with collection as attrubute

Tags: oracle, object, plsql

In oracle database I have created type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE DOSSIER_RESULT AS OBJECT
(
  id           number,
  user_id      number
)
```

Then I created the collection of this type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE DOSSIER_RESULTS_ARRAY AS TABLE OF DOSSIER_RESULT
```

Then I added one more attribute in first type definition like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE DOSSIER_RESULT AS OBJECT
(
  id           number,
  user_id      number,
  child        DOSSIER_RESULTS_ARRAY

)
```

But it compiled with error

```
Error: PLS-00201: identifier 'DOSSIER_RESULTS_ARRAY' must be declared
```

The question is: How can I create an Object type with collection of objects of this type in it?

Comment: you can't do that in Oracle with object types.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? In 11gR2 and 12cR2 that throws "ORA-02303: cannot drop or replace a type with type or table dependents", not PLS-00201.

Comment: that's because before updating type DOSSIER_RESULT need to drop type DOSSIER_RESULTS_ARRAY. Then - we are updating type DOSSIER_RESULT , compiling it, then compiling type DOSSIER_RESULTS_ARRAY

Comment: @AlexPoole i use Oracle 11.2.0.3.0 and i get the same error like wamik

Comment: we use Version: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: @hotfix, you sure?

Comment: Well, yes, if you drop the table type to avoid the ORA-02303 then obviously that won't exist when you recreate the object type. Anyway, you can't do this as far as I can see; even if you try to force it you'll get `ORA-04055: Aborted: "DOSSIER_RESULTS_ARRAY" formed a non-REF mutually-dependent cycle with "DOSSIER_RESULT"`, or vice versa depending on whether you drop the table type. You could use a subtype but that's not quite the same thing. Maybe you need to step back and explain your goal, and why you want to use objects at all.

Comment: @Wamik, yes i'm sure. you can try to work with a subtype of DOSSIER_RESULT. here you can add a member with a collection with super types. maybe it could be a solution